# Finding firing angle to shoot a projectile a given distance

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate what angle a gun has to be aimed for the projectile to fly a given distance considering air resistance. So for example if I want my projectile to fly 200m what angle do I have to aim my gun if the initial velocity of the bullet is 800 m/s, the air resistance is $-0.002\ m/s^2$ and gravity is $9.81\ m/s^2$.

I would be happy if someone could help me come up with a solution.

The best way I came up with is stepping thru the bullets flight path with a program I wrote calculating the new velocity of the bullet each step but this only gives me the flight time and distance for a known angel not the other way around.

Comment: Evidently you are comfortable with both designing an iterative method and programming it. Why not use this approach again? Estimate an angle and then improve it according to the error direction of the result.

Comment: @Nij i did that now i just have to find a balance between accuracy and speed i was hoping for a perfect solution :-)